reportlab acroform using cyrillic characters
How in reportlab set acroForm textfield value using cyrillic characters?
This code leads to the error:
form.textfield(name='fname', tooltip='First Name',
                   value='тест',
                   x=110, y=635, borderStyle='inset',
                   borderColor=magenta, fillColor=pink, 
                   width=300,
                   textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Documents/WORK/ALCO/mtx_trac/v3/pdf_form/SKY_WO/test.py", line 53, in 
create_simple_form()
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Documents/WORK/ALCO/mtx_trac/v3/pdf_form/SKY_WO/test.py", line 16, in create_simple_form
form.textfield(name='fname', tooltip='First Name',
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wo-skypartner-s9LzkY4i-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py", line 912, in textfield
return self._textfield(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wo-skypartner-s9LzkY4i-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py", line 828, in _textfield
ap = self.txAP(
^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wo-skypartner-s9LzkY4i-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py", line 711, in txAP
stream('%%(_4bw)s %s Td\n(%s) Tj' % (y,escPDF(line)))
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wo-skypartner-s9LzkY4i-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py", line 82, in escPDF
return escapePDF(s).replace('%','\045')
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/andrew.romm/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wo-skypartner-s9LzkY4i-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reportlab/lib/rl_accel.py", line 150, in escapePDF
r.append(_ESCAPEDICT[c])
~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
KeyError: 1090
